# Why is the "Hello world" printed 2 times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multiprocessing, fork, node-cluster

Why dose the program print "Hello World" 2 times rather than only 1 time? The console.log is excuted before cluster.fork().

```
import * as cluster from "cluster";

console.log("Hello World");

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    const worker = cluster.fork();
    worker.disconnect();
}
```

The following c program prints "Hello World" only 1 time

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   printf("HelloWorld/n");
   fork();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cluster.fork` method (through [`child_process.fork`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options), which it [calls](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works)) does not do a `fork` syscall like you'd have in UNIX. It *does* create a new child process, like fork would, but that new child process starts with an entirely new instance of the interpreter, and that new interpreter starts executing the script from the beginning. You're seeing the `console.log` executed once in the parent process and once in the child process.

The docs for `child_process.fork` briefly mention  this...

> Unlike the fork(2) POSIX system call, child_process.fork() does not clone the current process.

...but I would still say the name is confusing.

To work around this, you will probably want to move your initialization logic (in this example the `console.log` call) into the `if (cluster.isMaster)` block.

Answer (score 0):

cluster.fork creates a new child process and executes the same code. You should check if the process is the master or not and then execute code that you want inside either the if block or else block.

```
import * as cluster from "cluster";


if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log("Hello World from master");
    const worker = cluster.fork();
    worker.disconnect();
} else {
    console.log("Hello World from others");
}
```